# SQL Server Log Shipping Alert Job Issue

Tags: sql-server, jobs, logs

We have log shipping taking place between *server A* and *server B*.

- The logs are backed up every 15 minutes on *server A*.
- Over on *server B*, the logs are copied every 15 minutes successfully.
- The logs are restored on *server B* once per day at 3:35am successfully.

My issue is the alert job on *server B* is running every 2 minutes. It runs perfect for 45 minutes after the restore at 3:35am and then on the 47th minute, it fails and fails every 2 minutes until the next restore the next time at 3:35am

The threshold was set for 45 minutes so that part was correct.

**My current considerations**

This is what I'm thinking:

- The copy job is working and I would get alert if it failed.
- The restore job is working and I would get alert if it failed.

**Questions**

Why would I need the alert job? There is no way it can succeed. Since I am only restoring once per day, after that first 45 minute threshold is reached, it is an automatic failure every 2 minutes from then on.

Does this job alert on both copy and restore? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the threshold to 23 hours 15 minutes...I assume the restore job is the one alerting, correct?  I believe there is an alert on all three.   possibly just backup and restore, but I don't have a LS setup in front of me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53303/discussion-on-answer-by-kevin3nf-sql-server-log-shipping-alert-job-issue).